# Documentation for AWS infrastructure as code

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

Recently, while trying to build a terraform IaC, I found that I couldn’t get the API Gateway to route to the Lambda properly. It turned out that when using the console AWS automatically assigns the permissions the gateway needs for the Lambda, but with IaC in terraform this must be assigned explicitly.

The above is understandable but for a newbie, to both AWS and terraform, confusing.

Is there documentation which explains the required components within an infrastructure connection, such as that above?

I know of the AWS docs and the terraform docs are particularly well thought out but none of it actually explains (as far as I’ve seen) that a certain resource is required in any particular (however common or obscure) setup. Inferring these connections from general searching is not a great replacement.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a documentation that lists "all of the required components" in one single page/area. But you can get different pieces of information from different docs, and as you mentioned AWS and Terraform do both a great job at this.

Talking about AWS, in the case of permissions in API gateway, I can think of two useful links (the 1st one is referenced from the 2nd one though):

- [How API Gateway resource policies affect authorization workflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-authorization-flow.html)
- [Control access for invoking an API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html)

I agree in the fact that sometimes it's a lot of guesses to translate AWS into terraform if you don't really know what you are trying to achieve. Usually when I am blocked on something that "should theoritically work" in IaC vs AWS console, I step back from the problem and try to figure out what kind of components am I really trying to glue together in AWS world. Then usually things become more obvious.

Because in terraform it's really creating small independant pieces of infrastructure and make them work together. Comparing with other IaC, in my experience it's a lot more granular than CloudFormation for instance.

A personal practice that helps me figure out things faster is to read every single intro doc of the components I am working on in Terraform. For instance, if I am writing lambda in terraform IaC, I would quickly read all the lambda_xxxx_yyyy intro parts to get less stuck and react faster when something fails. It usually works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't see such a documentation, but I can share my work-around for similar cases.

You can make changes you need using AWS console - manually, using UI. Then you can define resources you just created in your TF files, defining only/required required set of properties, even random values will work. Then you import what you created manually into resources you defined.

By running `terraform plan` you will see the differences, that will allow you to adjust your TF files accordingly.

After few iterations you will replicate what you have just done in the UI using TF. As a final test you can manually revert your changes, run `terraform apply` and ensure that everything works as expected.

Comment: Thank you, that’s actually brilliant. The problem I faced was that the permission object couldn’t be seen the in the console (or at least neither I nor my colleagues could find it.) 

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you would use the `import` command in this context, please?

Comment: Each terraform resource has slightly different way to reference original aws resource, for example here is a documentation [how to import s3 bucket](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket#import). So you sequence of actions would be: create bucket manually. Add minimal resource definition so `terraform plan` would pass. Then run import, using resource name you just added and correct reference from the documentation. Then run `terraform plan` and sync tf files according to the diff.

Comment: My particular tf file for the `apigateway` includes `aws_lambda_permission` to work correctly, but how would I know which items to include if I cannot know what has been included? I wouldn't think to include something for the lambda into the tf for the gateway, so (I think) would not have it completed by the `import`.

Comment: Since terraform apply works correctly - basics (minimal dependencies) are already covered. For sure there might be something else, and I do not think there is a silver bullet to figure it out automatically. I see two approaches here: 1) remove manually, create using TF and confirm that everything is working 2) go over TF documentation for related resources - you might identify something that you actually use there.